# How do HHMM (Hierarchical Hidden Markov Models) work and where to learn more?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I recently came across something called **Hierarchical Hidden Markov Models**. I am familiar with HMMs, but not HHMMs.

I have two questions.

1. I can't fully understand the procedure after reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_hidden_Markov_model  . Specifically, a) Is the "terminating state" an actual state, but with only one possible next outcome? Or does it just signify an "automatic" vertical transition? b) Does a data point ever exist in one of the "outer" states? Or is the meaning of an "outer state" just a conceptual transition into the set of "inner states" corresponding to that outer state?
2. I am struggling to find any kind of comprehensive (preferably introductory) resource on this topic, keeping in mind I'm not a PhD. Are there any good books, papers, or articles you could recommend, that have an emphasis on the practical application of this method (how to use/design such models etc.)? Any good R packages for it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you feel is missing in the papers linked in [the Wikipedia page on hierarchical HMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_hidden_Markov_model)?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I think the answer to my first question is partially there (I'll edit my first question to incorporate the Wiki article info), but what is severely missing from the Wiki article is practical/applicable information about how to about setting this up, any practical considerations for what tends to work better/worse etc.